# SPI_GETMOUSE mouse threshold values

Tags: winapi, mouse, msdn

### SPI_GETMOUSE

*Retrieves the two mouse threshold values and the mouse acceleration. The pvParam parameter must point to an array of three integers that receives these values.*

And more information about the two mouse thresholds in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is :

*The system applies two tests to the **specified relative mouse motion** when applying acceleration. If the **specified distance** along either the x or y axis is greater than the first mouse threshold value, and the mouse acceleration level is not zero, the operating system doubles the distance. If the **specified distance** along either the x- or y-axis is greater than the second mouse threshold value, and the mouse acceleration level is equal to two, the operating system doubles the distance that resulted from applying the first threshold test. It is thus possible for the operating system to multiply **relatively-specified mouse motion** along the x- or y-axis by up to four times.*

What are the **specified relative mouse motion** , **specified distance** and **relatively-specified mouse motion** here as no distance or no motion is prespecified before the mouse is moving ? And how they are determined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mouse_event` function that you linked to is used to simulate mouse motion and button clicks. So you can call this in a program to move the mouse and/or click mouse buttons without the user doing so.

There is a set of flags passed to the `mouse_event` function, along with  x and y values (and other stuff not relevant to your question). One of the flag values - `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` - specifies that the x and y values you pass to `mouse_event` are absolute. If that flag is *not* set, then the x and y are relative values.

So in the case you're asking about - the **specified relative mouse motion**, for example - is just the xy values passed to `mouse_event` when the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag is not set.

Comment: Thanks..now I understand about the two threshold values and Enhance Precision field.